# High latency when streaming to google cloud speech on first audio result only

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi

I have google cloud speech setup on a raspberry pi for a voice assistant and while the entire system is working I am facing an unusual problem.

When I just boot up the system and send a audio stream to google cloud for real time processing it returns the result after about 15-20 seconds. The subsequent audio requests sent are returning within 1-2 seconds. This behaviour also reappears if the system is already running and I don't make a voice request for ~5-10 mins.

I'm using the node.js SDK. Here is my config file:

```
config:{
        encoding: "LINEAR16",
        sampleRateHertz: 16000,
        languageCode: 'en-us'
    },
    singleUtterance: true,
    interimResults: false
```

I don't send more than 4 seconds of audio at a time as the stream is forcibly closed if it exceeds this time.

I am able to consistently reproduce this issue but can't seem to understand why only the first query when the system is booted up or is inactive for a while takes so long to return a result.

Any ideas on how to approach debugging this?

Edit: I only seem to be facing this issue on the raspberry pi. There is no such first query delay on my mac.

Comment: network connectivity settings?  dhcp?  dns resoiving? timeout?  authentication? sleep mode of your hardware?

Comment: @jcuypers no network issues and no sleep issues or timeout either. Authentication is fine as well :(

Comment: But do you use DHCP or not?  can you see anything in logs about what's happening?

Comment: @jcuypers yes DHCP is enabled. Which logs should I be looking at?

Comment: I don't actually use raspberry pi, but espressif ESP32.  anyways some of the problems look similar.  there must be some logs somewhere about connecitivy.    please try to provide a static ip address just to be sure. (are you connected through wireless or wired)

Comment: In short your lease time of you dhcp might be short or the processing of getting connectivity up for a tiny device is much longer than a pc.   I had it happen with IP config over wireless.   15s to get up to send 500ms worth of data...

Comment: @jcuypers I'm connected through wireless. No option for a wired connection. I will check connectivity logs but the result is actually always returned. it just is consistently returned after 17 secs the first time or after a period of inactivity which makes me doubt it's a connectivity issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189018/discussion-between-shekit-and-jcuypers).

Comment: thats what i'm talking about.  initial connectivity or after sleep.  network connectivity setup is very slow.  just check the internet you might find something on how to check this for raspberry

Comment: Any luck / feedback on the solution?